# DAX - Rank by product category

Tags: powerbi, dax, ranking

I am trying to create a ranking for each product grouping in the product table (Product, Model, Product subcategory, Category).

I was unsuccessful with the rank by category.

[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to understand why the same formula pattern doesn't work for only the category.

```
Rank by Category = 
RANKX(
    ALLSELECTED('Product'[Category]),
    [Amount]
)
Amount = 
SUMX(
    Sales,
    Sales[Sales Amount]
)
```

Any input would be appreciated.

[Attached PowerBI file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Amkf-sbfo75s22gG7wQUG_4nk7fYjj0c/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is a little tricky; You get different output because your rank "Rank by Category" by two-column instead of one (as in rest of your example). The second column which is involved in your calculation is this one you are using to sort 'Product'[Category]; Change this to the default and you get a "correct" rank.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input.
The ranking calculation gives the ranking I am looking for by removing the Product[Category] sort by column as you indicated or adding the column Product[Sorting] in the ALLSELECTED.
I've been stuck on this for a while not quite understanding why the calculation didn't work.
I am still very new to powerbi and dax which I've been learning through lectures and ebooks. Although, I don't quite understand yet why the calculation is doing that, but I can pin point what to look into now to understand the why. So very much appreciated.